# Удаление элементов из списка

Tags: python, list

Здравствуйте!

Python изучаю несколько дней. Есть задача: в строке удалить слова, заканчивающиеся заданным символом. Накропал что-то похожее, но есть одна проблема - если нужно удалить последнее слово, оно удаляется, без проблем, НО предпоследний элемент дублируется.
Прошу помочь в решении проблемы.

Вот моя "наработка":

```
a=input().split()
for word in range(len(a)):
    a[word]=str(a[word])

sym=input()
sym=str(sym)
print('Введенная строка:', '\n ', a, '\n''Искомый символ:','\n',sym)

a==[a[word] for a[word] in a if not a[word].endswith(sym)]
print('Полученная строка:', '\n', a)
```

Comment: Почему оператор сравнения "==" в строке a == [a[word] for a[word] in a if not a[word].endswith(sym)] ?

Comment: пардон, заметил слишком поздно.
с "=" вместо "==" та же самая ситуация.

Answer (score 6):

На поставленный вопрос не отвечу, предложу своё решение. Потому что подобные задачи нужно решать средствами, которые специально сделаны для решения таких задач (каламбур). Потому что лучше сразу научиться правильно, чем потом переучиваться.

```
x = filter( lambda x : x.endswith("e"), list("one two three".split()) )
```

upd:
Во-первых писать так `[a[word] for a[word] in a if not a[word].endswith(sym)]` не нужно, это тяжелое наследие с/с++. В Питоне есть хорошая система итерирования, нужно использовать её `[ x for x in a if not x.endswith(sym) ]`. В таком вариант всё работает, слова фильтруются.

Comment: огромное спасибо за наводку на мысль :)

Comment: `e_words = [w for w in "one two three".split() if w.endswith("e")]` Ни к чему `list()` вокруг результата `.split()` добавлять (масло маслянное). Лучше генератор списков вместо `filter` + `lambda` использовать, если нет готовой именованной функции или если код для Питона 2/3 одновременно пишется. Кстати у вас код *оставляет* слова, а не удаляет (то есть `not` перед условием можно поставить).

Answer (score 1):

Вообще Вы написали что-то странное... Какой это python?
В python 3.x `input()` возвращает строку, с ней ничего не надо делать.
В 2.x — надо юзать raw_input, это во-первых:

```
words = raw_input('Введите строку').split()
```

Во-вторых, даже если вы используете for, делайте это правильно:
    for word in words: word = str(words)
Так Вы переберете все элементы массива.

Вообще советую почитать [стиль кода в языке python](http://share.auditory.ru/2010/Alex.Smirnov/python_code_styleguide.pdf) и дзен питона:

```
>>> import this
```

Что же по поставленной Вами задаче, то да, она решается списковыми сборками (или как их там?):

```
words = raw_input('').split()
a = raw_input('')
print [word for word in words if not word.endswith(a)]
print [word for word in words if word.endswith(a)]
```

Решение для Python 2.7